# Changing a Key Value Depending on Another Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function like this:

```
foreach($data as $line) {
    if(substr($line,0,1) == "A") {
        if(!$first) {
            $parts = explode(chr(9),$line);

            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($parts); echo "</pre>";
```

When printed returns multiple arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1188
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_2
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1188
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_3
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1186
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 101_2
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1188
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 302
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1161
    [4] => 0
)
```

Is it possible to 'only' select the keys ([1]) which have values _1,2,3, (if they exist)
and replace the key ([2]) with the same value, so the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1187
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1188
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 100_3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1186
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 101_2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1188
    [4] => 0
)

Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 302
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 1161
    [4] => 0
)
```

I tried to make lots of entries like this but they don't work (I cant get the key right):

```
foreach($parts as $key => $value) {

    if ($value == '100_1') {$parts[$key] = '1';};
    if ($value == '100_2') {$parts[$key] = '2';};
    if ($value == '100_3') {$parts[$key] = '3';}}
```

But this would be pure madness as there are over 50 different values and arrays any help would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach($data as $line) {
    if(substr($line,0,1)=="A") {
        if(!$first) {
            $parts = explode(chr(9), $line);
            list($num1, $num2) = explode('_', $parts[1]);
            $parts[2] = isset($num2) ? $num2 : $parts[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello mate you are the best, it worked first time I cant believe it thanks a lot. p.s I have another question, sort of a follow on from earlier question I posted, so Ill post it soon or maybe tomorrow. Many thanks. Dam just noticed that its affecting all the arrays rather than just the ones with the _. Can you help?